# Call only one function at a time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, oop

I am creating a login and register example function using php OOP method with ajax.

When i click on login button it automatically fires the register function as well and when click on register fires login function. I know the issue is when i create an object and calls both the functions below class. I want to know is there any way that i can call only one function at one time. Here is the code:

**Ajax**

```
function login() {

    jQuery('#loginform').on('submit', (function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'scripts/controller.php/login',
            type: 'POST',
            data: new FormData(this),
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function() {
                jQuery('#btn-login').html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-fw"></i>');
            },
            success: function(data) {
                if(data == 'Logged in') {
                    jQuery('.result').show();
                    jQuery('.result').html(data);
                    jQuery('#btn-login').html('Login');
                }
                else {
                    jQuery('.result').html(data);
                    jQuery('.result').show();
                    jQuery('#btn-login').html('Login');
                }
            }
        });
    }));

}

function register() {

    jQuery('#signupform').on('submit', (function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'scripts/controller.php/register',
            type: 'POST',
            data: new FormData(this),
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function() {
                jQuery('#btn-signup').html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-fw"></i>');
            },
            success: function(data) {
                if(data === 'An email has been sent. Please verify your account with in 3 days.') {
                    jQuery('.result').show();
                    jQuery('.result').fadeOut(5000);
                    jQuery('.result').html(data);
                    jQuery('#btn-signup').html('Sign Up');
                    jQuery('.result').html(data);
                    jQuery('#signupform')[0].reset();
                }
                else {
                    jQuery('.result').show();
                    jQuery('.result').html(data);
                    jQuery('#btn-signup').html('Sign Up');
                }
            }
        });
    }));

}
```

**PHP Code**

```
<?php

    require('model.php');

    class curd {

        /************************************************/
                /*** LOGIN **/    
        /************************************************/

        public function login() {

            $restricted = array('--', '#', "'--", '/*', '*/', '/**/', '/*', '1/0', '*/ 1', "'", ';', '1=1','true','false', 'BEGIN', '+', '||', '|', "' or 1=1/*", "') or '1'='1--", "') or ('1'='1--", '*', 'drop' );

            $userEmail = strip_tags(stripcslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email'])));
            $password = strip_tags(stripcslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['password'])));

            if(in_array($userEmail, $restricted) or in_array($password, $restricted)) {
                echo 'Avoid SQL injection attacks.';
            }
            else if(!filter_var($userEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                echo 'Invalid email address.';
            }
            else if(strlen(trim($userEmail)) < 5) {
                echo 'Minimum characters in email are 5.';
            }
            else if(strlen(trim($password)) < 5) {
                echo 'Minimum characters in password are 5.';
            }
            else {
                $model = new curd_model();
                echo $model -> login($userEmail, md5(sha1($password)));
            }

        }

        /************************************************/
                /*** REGISTER **/    
        /************************************************/

        public function register() {

            $restricted = array('--', '#', "'--", '/*', '*/', '/**/', '/*', '1/0', '*/ 1', "'", ';', '1=1','true','false', 'BEGIN', '+', '||', '|', "' or 1=1/*", "') or '1'='1--", "') or ('1'='1--", '*', 'drop' );

            $username = strip_tags(stripcslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['username'])));
            $userEmail = strip_tags(stripcslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email'])));
            $password = strip_tags(stripcslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['password'])));
            $question = strip_tags(stripcslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['question'])));
            $answer = strip_tags(stripcslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['answer'])));

            if(in_array($userEmail, $restricted) or in_array($password, $restricted) or in_array($userEmail, $restricted) or in_array($question, $restricted) or in_array($answer, $restricted)) {
                echo 'Avoid SQL injection attacks.';
            }
            else if(!filter_var($userEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                echo 'Invalid email address.';
            }
            else if(strlen(trim($userEmail)) < 5) {
                echo 'Minimum characters in email are 5.';
            }
            else if(strlen(trim($password)) < 5) {
                echo 'Minimum characters in password are 5.';
            }
            else {
                $model = new curd_model();
                echo $model -> register($username, $userEmail, md5(sha1($password)), $question, $answer);
            }

        }
    }

    $object = new curd();
    $object -> login();
    $object -> register();

?>
```

Comment: Why does you PHP code call both login and register methods? You should probably have individual controllers for each action. And please use PDO or Mysqli with prepared/parameterized queries so you can remove all the strip/tags etc. And please use the PHP password lib, md5 is horrible horrible practice.

Comment: thanks for the response i want to work only in one controller file. Like codeigniter i always make only one file for controller similarly i want only one file here. And regarding to the version i an using mysqli.

Comment: You at least need some logic to route the request to the correct action for different routes (URLs).

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you'll load the file the following lines would run:

```
   $object = new curd();
    $object -> login();
    $object -> register();
```

And therefore, both of the login and register functions would run.
You have 2 options:

1. Split those functions into 2 different files.
2. In your Ajax, add a parameter which would tell this file which function to run.

In MVC you might have a Routing mechanism (for instance: /user/login -> Controller User -> Method login)
In case you don't, you can simply use a query string, like: `/scripts/controller.php?do=login`  and in your php file have a condition:

```
   $object = new curd();

$do = $_GET['do'];
    if($do == 'login'){
         $object -> login();
    } else {
         $object -> register();
    }
```

and in your ajax, update the request url:

```
jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'scripts/controller.php?do=register',
```

(for login request as well .. ?do=login)

Comment: thanks man i didn't tried this but hope fully this will solve the problem